# How to know when to divide, factorise or move terms when making x the subject of a formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are many ways of making something the subject of a formula, like making every term have the same denominator, factorisation, dividing every term by the same thing. However, I often get confused by which operation to use. 
For example, if I have $\frac xa = \frac 2x - \frac xb$ and I want to make b the subject in terms of x and a, what should I do? The final answer is $\frac {(x^2)(a)}{2a-x^2}$. I got it using a really long-winded way where I tried everything I could but it wasn’t efficient. The suggested method is much simpler but I don’t see how they know when to use what operation.
This is the correct method:
$$\frac xa = \frac 2x - \frac xb$$
$$\frac 2x = \frac xa + \frac xb$$
$$\frac 2x = \frac {xb+xa}{ab}$$
$$2ab = (x^2) b+ (x^2)a$$
$$2ab-(x^2)b = (x^2) a$$
$$b(2a -x^2) = (x^2) a$$
$$b = \frac {(x^2)a}{2a-x^2}$$
OR it could be done this way (also the suggested method):
$$\frac xa = \frac 2x - \frac xb$$
$$\frac {x(xb)}{xab} = \frac {2(ab) - x(xa)}{xab}$$
$$x(xb) = 2(ab)-x(ab)$$
$$bx^2 = 2ab -(x^2)a$$
$$b(x^2 -2a) =-(x^2)a$$
$$b(2a-x^2) = (x^2)a$$
$$b = \frac {x^2 a}{2a-x^2}$$

Comment: To solve a fraction equation, the best way is to multiply the equation with the least common multiplier of the denominators, in this case $abx$. Of course, $a,b,x$ are not allowed to be $0$ after that and if such a solution occurs, it must be eliminated.

Comment: It is really hard to parse your fractions.  Please use a \frac.  Also, it appears that some of your equalities are false (or should really be commas).  For instance, the second equality in the first block of fractions seems to imply that $x/a=x/a+x/b2/x$.

Comment: I have edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I see that you know what to do, so what is the problem?

Comment: I don’t know where to start when doing these kind of problems. There are suggested methods, but if I’m given a problem without any solution, I don’t know what to do. Is there any hint for knowing when to factorise, common denominator etc. ?

Comment: I think that @Peter advice is good. Even if you don't get the least common denominator, just multiply be the product of all denominators, in this case (abx), then simplify. Keep in mind that you are after a form like $b$=some expression free of $b$. This is one of those things that requires some practice.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x}{b} = \frac{2}{x} - \frac{x}{a}$$

$$\frac{x}{b} = \frac{2a-x^2}{xa}$$

$$b = \frac{x^2a}{2a-x^2}$$